# JavaScript からデフォルトのロケールを取得・変更したい

Tags: javascript

[Number の toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/toLocaleString) や [Date の toLocaleString()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) をロケールを指定せずに実行した場合、

```
Number(1234).toLocaleString();
-> "1,234"

(new Date).toLocaleString();
-> "‎2014‎年‎12‎月‎27‎日‎ ‎18‎:‎50‎:‎30"
```

と表示されました。（IE11の場合）

おそらくロケールのデフォルト値が "ja-JP" になっているからと思われますが、このデフォルト値をJavaScriptから取得・変更することは出来るでしょうか？

Answer (score 5, accepted):

言語はChrome,Firefox等では`navigator.language`、IEでは`navigator.userLanguage`,`navigator.browserLanguage`で取得することができます。

但しデフォルト値はJavaScriptから変更することは出来なかったかと思います。

参考: https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/Web/API/window.navigator.language