# スクレイピングで、テキストの一部が自動的に英語に翻訳された状態で取得される

Tags: python, python3, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Seleniumのスクレイピングについてご質問させていただきます。

現在、↓のページのスクレイピングスクリプトを書いています。
https://www.gakujo.ne.jp/2022/company/baseinfo/22242/

**環境**
MacBook Pro
Google Chrome
Jupyter Notebook
Selenium

**症状**
見出しの一部（『プロフィール』）が自動的に英語に翻訳された状態で取得されてしまう。
↓今回取得したパート

[image: 今回取得したパート]

**スクリプト**

```
driver.get('https://www.gakujo.ne.jp/2022/company/baseinfo/22242/')
company_profile = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_MyBaseInfoCtl_pnlProfile')
company_profile = company_profile.text
print(company_profile)
```

↓結果

```
profile
【医療×人×技術＝∞】医療業界へ新たな価値を提供し続ける「企業」の魅力とは？
HR talks "Pay attention here!"
日本の医療界の課題に挑む「リーディングカンパニー」
医師と医療機関を徹底サポートする【民間医局】を運営
医療×VR、医療×ドローン、医療×食などの集合知による新提案、、、、（以下全て日本語で取得される）
```

※見出しの **『プロフィール』が『profile』** に、**『人事担当が語る「ココに注目！」』が『HR talks “Pay attention here!“』** になってしまいます。

**補足**
ページによっては、テキスト全て英語で取得されてしまうケースや全て日本語で取得できるケースなど、**症状はページによってバラバラ**です。ググっても良い解決策が見当たらないので、ご質問させていただきました。（google翻訳やDeepLのプラグインを入れていることとか関係ありそうでしょうか？？）

知見をお持ちの方がいらっしゃれば、アドバイスをお願い致します。

Comment: サーバー側は UA のロケールを Javascript の返却値で判断しているのかも https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/2684/

Comment: プラグインが原因だとすれば、それらを無効にすると解決するかもしれません。[Disable Shockwave Flash plugin using Selenium with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38861370) もっとも、対象のサイトの場合には Selenium を使わなくても requests でスクレイピングする事も可能かと思います。

Comment: @774RR コメントありがとうございました。大変参考になりました。

Comment: @metropolis プラグインが原因の線から色々探って解答に結びつきました。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 1):

ヘッドレスChromeの言語設定を英語→日本語にすることで解決しました。

**参考:**

[【Selenium】ヘッドレスChromeの言語設定を英語→日本語にする](https://yuki.world/selenium-headless-chrome-en-to-ja/)

以下のオプションを追記

```
options.add_argument('--lang=ja-JP')
```

ありがとうございました。